# Need an advise how to join two subsurf meshes

Tags: mesh

I need a best practice advice on the following.

I want to join two meshes which are both in one object. The three claws are seperate and I want to join them to the wrist.

I have done this before by deleting the faces on the ends of the wrist stump and the finger stumps, then bridge looped them. But there is often a problem with the number of edges not matching for each mesh. I.e. wrist has 4 edges and the fingers have 6 or more.

What is best practise to accomplish this and creating good topology for deformation?

[image: joining two meshes with subsurf mod]

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Select the object you want to join. Select the other. Then type Ctrl J.

If the two are the same object. Edit mode: select the vertices you want to join. Type W then Merge.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. 
I know how to do a simple merge of vertices and how to join two objects but I wanted to know of a best practice to "merge" two meshes like the ones above yet still maintain a rather good topology like I described in my question. Merging, welding etc on subsurf mod gives strange outcome sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is best to apply subsurf modifier and delete faces to connect both meshes in edit mode using Snap - Vertex - Closest or use Alt + M. 
Also remodeling is most likely necessary so that both edges which are to join have the same number of opposing edges. Sadly the subsurf modifier is gone then but due to lack of knowledge, this seems to be best practice (to me).

Comment: Applying Subsurf is destructive change to mesh which can be not convenient due to geometry increase and hence is recommended only at the end of worfklow. Increase / decrease amount of edge loops on the connecting meshes according to the linked answer to your question (one way) and then with Subsurf not applied test the result